# Displaying the correct datatable out of a group of datatables

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Referring to [this](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18365&p=57049#p56921) post on primefaces forum.
Has someone got any idea how can we use multiple datatable on the same page but only display the correct one?
 
My problem is that i have a view-Scoped bean whose properties contain data from different tables from a database. I have multiple datatables for data of each database table. Now i want to display the datatable on the basis value selected from `<p:selectOneMenu>` (encircled in red color).
this screenshot would explain a bit further.

[image]

Comment: What is the correct datatable? Conditional rendering is standard in jsf.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new to JSF thats why did not know how to change visibility of a selected datatable.

Comment: By the way, i've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic approach would be to let the `rendered` attribute of the tables depend on the selected item of the menu.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.table}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="players" itemLabel="Players" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="jobs" itemLabel="Jobs" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="business" itemLabel="Business" />
    ...
    <p:ajax update="tables" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<h:panelGroup id="tables">
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.players}" rendered="#{bean.table == 'players'}">
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.jobs}" rendered="#{bean.table == 'jobs'}">
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
    <p:dataTable value="#{bean.business}" rendered="#{bean.table == 'business'}">
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is easy to implement, but you end up with a lot of code in the view (which can of course be split over `<ui:include>` files). The more advanced and reuseable approach would be to let the `value` of the single table depend on the selected item of the menu and use [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf) to generate columns dynamically.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.table}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.tables}" />
    <p:ajax listener="#{bean.changeModel}" update="table" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:dataTable id="table" value="#{bean.model}" var="item">
    <p:columns value="#{bean.columns}" var="column">
        <h:outputText value="#{item[column]}" />
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

with something like:

```
public void changeModel() {
    model = populateModelBasedOn(table);
    columns = populateColumnsBasedOn(table);
}
```

This only allows less fine-grained control whenever you want to add more specialized columns. You'd probably want to work with tag files instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My actual intention was to do all that you've mentioned. Please suggest me which approach would be more useful? tag file, composite components or changing table model on the basis of selected value?

Comment: In my question, i've referred to a [Post](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18365&p=57049#p56921) on primefaces forum, in which someone said to me: "Or you use many datatables, but with a rendered="#{myBean.condition}" to show only the correct datatable =)
Mixing it with ui:include + ui:params, you have only one code for the same datatable!" please tell me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By the grace of God. After lots of struggle! i finally achieved **[this](http://s19.postimage.org/kt8xiy80z/image.png)**!
For this i pay bundles of thanks to BalusC for his expert tips
So i would like to share my solution with all.
So here is what i did in my xhtml file:

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{dbmBean.selectedTable}" style="height:27px" >
    <c:forEach items="#{dbmBean.tableNames}" var="table">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{table.value}" itemValue="#{table.key}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</p:selectOneMenu>
<p:commandButton value="Go" action="#{dbmBean.goToTable}" ajax="false" />
...
<p:dataTable binding="#{dbmBean.table}" var="row" rowIndexVar="index">
<f:facet name="header"/>
<p:columns value="#{dbmBean.columns}" var="column" columnIndexVar="colIndex" >  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            #{column.header}  
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{row[column.property]}"/>
    </p:columns>
</p:dataTable>
```

and in the backing bean:

```
public class DatabaseManagerBean implements Serializable {
    private List<ColumnModel> columns; // Column model is a simple class with two string properties: header, property
    ...    
    public void goToTable() {
        int tableIndex = new Integer(this.selectedTable);
        switch (tableIndex) {
            case 1:
                 Players tempPlayers = new Players(); //the class which get data from a database table
                 this.players = tempPlayers.getAllPlayers();
                 this.columnNames = tempPlayers.getColumnNames();
                 for (String colName : columnNames) {
                    columns.add(new ColumnModel(colName.toUpperCase(), colName));
                 }
                 table.setRendered(true);
                 table.setValue(this.players);
                 break;
                 ...
                 default:
                 table.setRendered(false);
         } //end of switch statement
    } //end of goToTable() method
} //end of DatabaseManagerBean
```

This code snippet would work exactly as i wanted in this screenshot! :-)

[image]

Also if someone find something left unexplained or missing, please write a comment.
And again hats off to BalusC. Because without his hints, i won't be able to achieve this objective. :-)
I would also like to say thanks to Optimus Prime and the PrimeFaces team to create such wonderful Faces. :-)
i would also pay my thanks to the Stackoverflow team, for providing us such a wonderful platform for such discussions! :-)
thank you all! :-)